# KeyError for os.envron['PATH'] in Visual Studio Code on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'v installed Visual Studio Code(1.19.1, 64bit) on Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit), Python 2.7 were already installed with ubuntu(by default), and numpy was installed by: sudo pip install numpy

I'v coded a file e.g. test.py with the following lines:

```
import numpy
print(10)
```

When I run this python file with F5 in Visual Studio Code, errors occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ml/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + extra_dll_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

It turns out that os.envrion['PATH'] throws this error, indicating key 'PATH' not exists in os.environ collections.

However, if I run test.py in terminal, everything gets ok, and os.environ["PATH"] returns the correct results.

Is there any suggestions about this issue, please?

Comment: Check the environment variable settings VS Code is using for Python.

Comment: Python configurations for VS Code remains unchanged, such as: "python.pythonPath": "python".  Is there any other place for environment variables?

Comment: FYI you don't want to set `python.pythonPath` to just `python`. It should be an absolute path if you're going to explicitly set it (otherwise use the `Select Interpreter` option to specify it). There's a chance that is throwing things off.

Comment: I tried both absolute path and "Select Interpreter" option，but the error remains. However, when I install numpy by "apt-get install python-numpy", and remove numpy previously installed by "pip install numpy", everything gets ok.  I was wondering why "pip" diden't work.

Comment: Ubuntu quite possibly tweaked something in their installation of Python and/or pip that made this not work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a known problem that should be fixed by the end of January. More details on the following GitHub issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/436

And the milestones due by January 29, 2018

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/milestone/2

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with some other Python libraries. Till the new version of VSCode is released, I have added a .env file with

`PATH=$PATH`

That seems to solve the issue for me and I am able to use Python debugger.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add this .env file? Thank you.

Comment: Create a file named ".env" in the root workspace folder. Copy the text that I mentioned in this file and launch the debugger. Now it should work for you.